# How to check that duplicated rows (based on one column) are identical after dealing with missing values in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, nan

I hope you're doing well.
So my problem is that I have some duplicated rows based on one column (column A), then I should handle missing values if they exist like in the following examples :

**- 1st example :**

```
    A   B   C
0   foo 2   3
1   foo nan nan
2   foo 1   4
3   bar nan nan
4   foo nan nan
```

Concerning this example, this case is invalid because row 0 and row 2 have different values in B or C (if there is a nan it's okay but if there is another value it's not okay).

**- 2nd example :**

```
    A   B   C
0   foo 2   3
1   foo nan nan
2   foo nan 3
3   bar 1   nan
4   foo 2   nan
```

This case is valid (the duplicated rows either have the same value in B and C or have nan), then we should handle missing values as following :

```
    A   B   C
0   foo 2   3
1   foo 2   3
2   foo 2   3
3   bar 1   nan
4   foo 2   3
```

Answer (score 1):

to check if it is a valid data frame, will return true is not valid:

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.drop('A', axis=1).isna().all(axis=1).sum() > 1).any()
```

fill the na if it is valid:

```
df[['B', 'C']] = df.groupby('A').transform(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill'))
```

Comment: df.dropna().duplicated().any() showed that the 2nd example also is invalid because it drops rows with nan.

Comment: yeah, just use `df.duplicated().any()` then, assuming you don't have other dup rows, I updated the answer too

Comment: Da Song, an invalid case is when we have different values in B or C (other than nan) concerning the duplicated rows.

Comment: ok, I guess the small example does not have that case, I updated the answer again. I will stop here, you will need to update the question with more detailed requirement if you need a more general answer

Answer (score 0):

As long as the matrix you are trying to recreate is:

```
A,B,C
foo, 2, 3
bar, 1, nan
```

Assuming that the code you are developing is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

first_example = {'A' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo'],
                'B' : [2, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan],
                'C' : [3, np.nan, 4, np.nan, np.nan]}



second_example = {'A' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo'],
                 'B' : [2, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2],
                 'C' : [3, np.nan, 3, np.nan, np.nan]}


df1 = pd.DataFrame(first_example)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(second_example)
```

You should try:

```
df1[['B_','C_']] = ['','']
df1.set_index('A', inplace=True)
df1.at['foo','B_'] = 2
df1.at['foo','C_'] = 3
df1.at['bar','B_'] = 1
df1.at['bar','C_'] = np.nan
df1 = df1.drop(columns=['B','C'])
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df1.columns = ['A','B','C']
```

Here is the output:
[image: Output]

Comment: No @girolamo, it's general, it is not related to this example.

Comment: How about generating a new dataframe that has the right matrix and then `pd.concat` to the df with other values?